# Monty Hall simulation not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, python-3.6

I've been trying out to solve the [monty hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) in Python in order to advance in coding, which is why I tried to randomize everything. The thing is: I've been running into some trouble. As most of you probably know the monty problem is supposed to show that changing the door has a higher winrate (66%) than staying on the chosen door (33%). For some odd reason though my simulation shows a 33% winrate for both cases and I am not really sure why.

Here's the code:

```
from random import *


def doorPriceRandomizer():
    door1 = randint(0,2) #If a door is defined 0, it has a price in it
    door2 = randint(0,2) #If a door is defined either 1 or 2, it has a goat in it.
    door3 = randint(0,2)
    while door2 == door1:
        door2 = randint(0,2)
    while door3 == door2 or door3 == door1:
        door3 = randint(0,2)
    return door1,door2,door3 #This random placement generator seems to be working fine.


while True:
    loopStart = 0
    amountWin = 0
    amountLose = 0
    try:
        loopEnd = int(input("How often would you like to run this simulation: "))
        if loopEnd < 0:
            raise ValueError
        doorChangeUser = int(input("[0] = Do not change door; [1] = Change door: "))
        if doorChangeUser not in range(0,2):
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Try again.\n")
    else:
        while loopStart != loopEnd:
            gameDoors = doorPriceRandomizer()
            inputUser = randint(0,2)
            if doorChangeUser == 0:
                if gameDoors[inputUser] == 0:
                    amountWin += 1
                    loopStart += 1
                else:
                    amountLose += 1
                    loopStart += 1
            elif doorChangeUser == 1:
                ChangeRandom = 0
                while gameDoors[ChangeRandom] == gameDoors[inputUser]:
                    ChangeRandom = randint(0,2)
                if gameDoors[ChangeRandom] == 0:
                    amountWin += 1
                    loopStart += 1
                else:
                    amountLose += 1
                    loopStart += 1

    print("Win amount: ",amountWin,"\tLose amount: ",amountLose)
```

What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate all help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and read [MCVE] to increase your chances of getting the help you need. Your code block that you post should follow the guidelines in [MCVE].

Comment: If anyone's interested, I did this, and I made the game a function, so you can run it tons of times in a loop to get the odds, and you can just call the function with no parameters to play it. If you have some free time check it out it would mean a lot too me: https://github.com/NoahCristino/montyhall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ChangeRandom = 0
while gameDoors[ChangeRandom] == gameDoors[inputUser]:
    ChangeRandom = randint(0,2)
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. Instead of checking if the `ChangeRandom` door is the same as the `inputUser` door, this checks if the `ChangeRandom` door and the `inputUser` door have the same value -- that is to say they're either both winners or both losers.

That said, that's not even what you want to do. What you want to do is to find a door that's not the user's input that IS a loser door, then switch to the OTHER one that isn't the user's input. This could be implemented with minimal change to your code as:

```
other_wrong_door = next(c for c, v in enumerate(gameDoors) if v != 0 and c != inputUser)
new_door = next(c for c, _ in enumerate(gameDoors) if c != inputUser and c != other_wrong_door)
```

But honestly this merits a re-examining of your code's structure. Give me a few minutes to work something up, and I'll edit this answer to give you an idea of how I'd implement this.

```
import random

DOORS = [1, 0, 0]

def runonce(switch=False):
    user_choice = random.choice(DOORS)
    if user_choice == 1:
        # immediate winner
        if switch:
            # if you won before and switch doors, you must lose now
            return False
        else:
            new_doors = [0, 0]  # remove the user-selected winner
            new_doors = [0]     # remove another loser
            return bool(random.choice(new_doors))
            # of course, this is always `0`, but
            # sometimes it helps to show it. In production you
            # wouldn't bother writing the extra lines and just return False
    else:
        if switch:
            new_doors = [1, 0]  # remove the user-selected loser
            new_doors = [1]     # remove another loser
            return bool(random.choice(new_doors))
            # as above: this is always True, but....
        else:
            return False  # if you lost before and don't switch, well, you lost.

num_trials = int(input("How many trials?"))
no_switch_raw = [run_once(switch=False) for _ in range(num_trials)]
switch_raw = [run_once(switch=True) for _ in range(num_trials)]

no_switch_wins = sum(1 for r in no_switch_raw if r)
switch_wins = sum(1 for r in switch_raw if r)

no_switch_prob = no_switch_wins / num_trials * 100.0
switch_prob = switch_wins / num_trials * 100.0

print( "         WINS    LOSSES   %\n"
      f"SWITCH:  {switch_wins:>4}    {num_trials-switch_wins:>6}  {switch_prob:.02f}\n"
      f"NOSWITCH:{no_switch_wins:>4}    {num_trials-no_switch_wins:>6}  {no_switch_prob:.02f}")
```

Comment: Hell, this is complicated.  I'll look into your solution to this problem later on, since I am pretty sure I can learn something from it. Quite a few things I didn't knew yet.. the shuffle function is one of them. Thanks for that. Right now though I've tried to insert those two lines of code you've written me before. It works, but I really do not understand what it does. Mind explaining those two lines a bit more in detail? I am trying to figure out what `next` does and how `for c in c` is supposed to work. How can a for-loop work without a defined variable?

Comment: `var for var in collection` is a genexp, or generator expression. You'll usually see them wrapped in square brackets, which make them "list comprehensions" `[var for var in collection]`, but since we only need one value I'm just using the raw genexp and calling `next` on it. `next` is a builtin method that draws the next value out of a generator.

Comment: the first expression (the first `var`) in the genexp is the values that get pulled out of the generator. So you could do a generator of perfect squares by doing `x**2 for x in range(1, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You have gotten the mechanics of the problem wrong so you are getting the wrong result. I have rewritten the choice mechanics, but I am leaving the user input stuff to you so that you can continue to learn python. This is one of many ways to solve the problem, but hopefully it demonstrates some things to you.

```
def get_choices():
    valid_choices = [0, 1, 2] # these are the values for a valid sample
    shuffle(valid_choices)    # now randomly shuffle that list
    return valid_choices      # return the shuffled list

def get_door(user_choice):
    return user_choice.index(0)


def monty_sim(n, kind):
    """

    :param n: number of runs in this simulation
    :param kind: whether to change the door or not, 0 - don't change, 1 = change door
    :return: (win_rate, 1 - win_rate)
    """
    wins = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        game_doors = get_choices()
        user_choice = get_door(get_choices()) # use the same method and find user door choice
        # so there are two branches.
        # In both, a door with a goat (game_door = 1) is chosen, which reduce the result to
        # a choice between two doors, rather than 3.
        if kind == 0:
            if user_choice == game_doors.index(0):
                wins += 1
        elif kind == 1:
            # so now, the user chooses to change the door
            if user_choice != game_doors.index(0):
                wins += 1
            # Because the original choice wasn't the right one, then the new
            # must be correct because the host already chose the other wrong one.

    win_rate = (wins / n) * 100
    return win_rate, 100 - win_rate


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 1000
    kind = 1
    wins, loses = monty_sim(n, kind)
    print(f'In a simulation of {n} experiments, of type {kind} user won {wins:02f} of the time, lost {loses:02f} of the time')
```